# Angularjs Scope in Jquery Modal popup

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope, modal-dialog

js 1.3 with jquery.
I have to display a form input in modal window. For which I have written a jquery function which will open the hidden dom content in Modal window.

```
ShowModal.open({
    content: $(".modal_content").html(), //Get html content form dom
})
```

Code for modal is working fine. The problem is the modal is not getting the controller's scope. I am using "Controller As" syntax for controller:

```
function controller(){
    bindVm = this;
    bindVm.data = ["Hello", "World"]
}
```

In Modal window

```
<div ng-controller="controller as bindVm">
    <div class="modal_content"> {{bindVm.data[0]}}</div>
</div>
```

The controller's code is working fine for normal page, but not working in modal window.

Note : I am also attaching html content using $compile

```
$modalContent.html($compile($modal_content)($scope));
```

Still not working. Anybody got something.

Answer (score 1):

In modal you need to resolve your variables or scopes and pass to modal controller then you can start to use them check here [Angular-UI Modal resolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30290311/angular-ui-modal-resolve)

[Pass parameter to modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18576454/pass-parameter-to-modal)

Comment: I am not using Angular-UI. I created my own custom modal function with jquery. Read the question carefully.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved. used $templateCache to get the template and attaching data to $scope instead of bindVm alias.

html:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="template1.html">
    <div class="modal_content"> {{data[0]}}</div>
</script>
```

JS:

```
$modalContent.html($compile($templateCache.get('template1.html'))($scope));
```

Working now.