# Binding from modal Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I pass the link of this example, I have a variable called "greeting" that changes its value in a modal window but does not bind. Do not share scope?

http://jsfiddle.net/Bibidesign/Lodkh4jy/7/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ui.bootstrap']);

myApp.controller('GreetingController', ['$scope', '$modal', function($scope,$modal) {
  $scope.greeting = 'Hello!';


  $scope.changeValues = function() {

        var modalInstance = $modal.open({

            templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',

            backdrop: 'static',

            scope: $scope, 

            controller: function($scope, $modalInstance) {

                    $scope.greeting = "Welcome";

              $scope.cancel = function(){
                         modalInstance.close();
                  }  

              $scope.ok = function(){
                         modalInstance.close();
                  }                

            }

        });

    };
}]);
```

Comment: The jsfiddle is working how I would expect to based on the code you shared here and in the fiddle. What are you expecting to happen, or think should be working differently?

Comment: @Tyler I expected all the "$scope.greeting" to change, if in the modal window it is "$ scope.greeting = Welcome" the text of "Hello!" change too to "Welcome"

Comment: When I open the modal window the text of Hello! change to Welcome

Comment: I thought so. The problem is, both `$scope.greeting` variables are on two different scopes. When you declare a controller for your modal and give it a `$scope` parameter, it is creating a new `$scope`, one level above the `$scope` from your `GreetingController`. 

What is the actual goal you are trying to achieve? From the modal name, my guess is you want to have a modal that opens and changes the value of a variable?

Comment: @Tyler Yes, that's right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are partially there. We just need to set up passing the variables between the `GreetingController` and the Modal `controller`. We will use the resolve property on the object passed into `$modal.open()` to pass a value to the modal `controller`, and than when we close the modal, we will pass back the new value through those the results object. We are also removing `scope: $scope`, because the controller declaration is overriding that scope copy, and we want to keep these scopes separate. Example to follow.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30293494/4606706) has a more thorough explanation of what is happening with the resolve, but it is essentially just a simplified way to resolve promises and guarantee data is in the controller before initializing the modal.

```
myApp.controller('GreetingController', ['$scope', '$modal', function($scope,$modal) {
    $scope.greeting = 'Hello!';


    // this will handle everything modal
    $scope.changeValues = function() {

        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
            backdrop: 'static',
            // resolve is an object with all the objects we will pass to the controller
            // I'm adding more than just greeting for examples sake
            resolve: {
                greeting: function () {
                    return $scope.greeting;
                },
                testData: function () {
                    return "This is some random test data";
                }
            }
            // on the controller parameters, we add the properties we are resolving
            controller: function($scope, $modalInstance, greeting, testData) {

                // the greeting variable passed in through resolve
                console.log('greeting', greeting); // expected output: greeting Hello!
                // the testData passed in through resolve
                console.log('testData', testData); // expected output: testData This is some random test data

                // this will be the greeting you are able to access on the modal
                // we can set this to the value from the resolve or a new value like below
                $scope.greeting = "Welcome";
                //$scope.greeting = greeting // this will set the modal to the value passed in from the resolve

                // NOTE*** I changed this call to dismiss()
                $scope.cancel = function(){
                    modalInstance.dismiss();
                }  

                $scope.ok = function(){
                    // what ever we pass in to close will be accessible in the result below
                    // we are passing in the new greeting - 'Welcome'
                    modalInstance.close($scope.greeting);
                }                
            }
        });

        // this is the majority of the new code
        modalInstance.result.then(function(okReturnObject){
            // this okReturnObject will be whatever you pass in to modalInstance.close()
            console.log('return', okReturnObject); // expectedOutput: return Welcome

            // this is where we are setting the original value to the new value from the modal
            $scope.greeting = okReturnObject;
        },function(){
            // will be run after modalInstance.dismiss()
            console.log("Modal Closed");
        });
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't url refer the `text/ng-template` as the templateUrl. Instead, add the html form in a separate html file and refer to that in the modal declaration.

Here's a working plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/lMZK0uGNsEmRjAN7teVZ?p=preview